# How i can stop graphql query after sending query in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I am using graphQl in flutter.
Can I stop the request after submitting the query and before receive response?

[image: i use this function for send query]

i use this function for send query now i want stop query after sending and before get response.

Comment: Can you share the code which you have done till now?

Comment: Yes. I'm edited my question.

Comment: Can you share your use case with an example, it will be easy to understand

Comment: No, I can't, everything is clear.

Comment: @moeinrunAppMyApp Did you find any solution for this?